# Calling an object from a function in an R package?

Tags: r, package

This is confusing me, so I hope I can explain it well...

I have created an R-package, and within that package I have 3 scripts (toy examples are below). 1 of the scripts generates some data/calculations and the remaining 2 scripts contain different plotting functions. For example, the scripts in my package look something like this...

The 1st script `genData.R` creates a matrix of values, does a calculation and returns a data frame:

```
# Matrix Funtion with rows = r and columns = c:
xMat <- function(r, c){
  Mat <- matrix(runif(r*c, 0, 1), nrow=r)
  Mat <- Mat * 10
  colnames(Mat) <- paste0("x", 1:c)
  df <- data.frame(Mat)
  df
}
```

The remaining scripts are similar to each other, the only difference between them is the type of plot they produce. They both contain a call to `xMat()`to generate the data and then plot the data using a separate plotting function. The 1st plotting script `plot1.R` looks like so:

```
#' @param r no of rows
#' @param c no of cols
#' @import ggplot2
#' @export

xFunc <- function(r,c){
  Val <- xMat(r,c)
  xPlot(Val)
}

xPlot <- function(df){
  myData <- df
  p <- ggplot(myData, aes(x1, x2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = x1))
  p
}
```

And similarly, the 2nd plotting function `plot2.R` script looks like so:

```
#' @param r no of rows
#' @param c no of cols
#' @import ggplot2
#' @import reshape
#' @export

xFunc.1 <- function(r,c){
  Val <- xMat(r,c)
  xPlot.1(Val)
}


xPlot.1 <- function(df){
  myData <- df
  df <-  melt(df)
  p <-ggplot(df, aes(x = df$variable, y = df$value)) + geom_line()
  p
}
```

What im trying to do is, if, say, I called the function `xFunc()` first, then it will call `xMat()` to generate the data etc.... but then afterwards, if I call `xFunc.1`, I don't want it to call `xMat` again and have to generate new data.

I want to be able to store the object `df` created by `xMat` and then when I call `xFunc.1` it just retrieves the object `df` instead of having to do the data generation/calculations again. I have edited this question to reflect that I cannot store the object `df` in the global environment. CRAN do not allow modifications to the users environment. I have been experimenting with creating a local environment within the package using `new.env()`, but I'm not sure how to make this work?

I imagine it might look something like this:

```
if(xMat has not previously been run){
execute xMat
}else{
If xMat has been run then
retrieve the df object previously created by xMat
}
```

I hope I explained that clearly.... Any suggestions as to how I would do this?

Comment: The simple way would be to have `xFunc` and `xMat` take a `data` argument, and the only call `xMat` if the `data` argument is missing. You would then have the user pass in the data argument to use the same data.The more complicated way would be to use `options` or something like that---this could be more constraining to the user, so I would think hard about use cases. There's probably a third option with R6 objects or reference classes, but I haven't really used those...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running these scripts in arbitrary order, and you're not restarting R.  You could

```
if(! exists("myXMatDf")){
    myXMatDf <- xMat(r,c)}
```

But that gets error-prone if you forget which values of `r` and `c` you last used.

If you want to save rerunning `xMat` even when you've, say, rebooted your machine, you can write to a cache.

```
if(file.exists("cache/myXMatDf.RData"){
  load("cache/myXMatDf.RData")
} else {
  myXMatDf <- xMat(r,c)
  save(myXMatDf, r, c, file = "cache/myXMatDf.RData"
}
```

# NOT RUN #

P.S. on `exists`:

```
R > y
Error: object 'y' not found
R > exists("y")
[1] FALSE
R > y <- 8
R > y
[1] 8
R > exists("y")
[1] TRUE
```

`exists` takes a string.  It tests whether there's anything in the environment by that name.  Before you run your script the first time, `myXMatDf` isn't bound - it doesn't have a value. `exists("myXMatDf")` is FALSE.  After you run your script `myXMatDf` is bound to a data frame. `exists("myXMatDf")` is TRUE.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong here, but the object `df` that is created within `xMat` will never be in the environment as 'data'. The function `xMat` will be in the environment as a 'function'. So `exists("df")` will always be `FALSE`. For example, if I run `xFunc` first and then use `exists("df")`, it is returning as `FALSE`

Comment: Good point, and I'm sorry I wasn't more explicit.  I was thinking of putting the `if(exists("myXMatDf")){..}` at the top level.  If you ran it inside a function, you'd have to do the assignment as `myXMatDf <<- xMat(r,c)`

Comment: had to edit my question to reflect my need to not store `df` in the global environment as per CRAN rules.